# Uso de meta keywords

Tags: html, seo

Os buscadores continuam a usar a tag meta como relevante?

Há vários artigos na internet dizendo que não,outros que sim,gostaria realmente de saber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim!

Dificilmente os buscadores irão abandonar estas tags.

Bing e Google tem inclusive algumas documentações como [esta](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/which-robots-metatags-does-bing-support-5198d240) e [esta](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=pt-BR) sobre a utilização destas tags.

Além de existirem diversos artigos como [este](http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2013/08/21/how-to-improve-your-sites-seo/) com a recomendação para utilizar estas tags, existem diversas [ferramentas](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meta-seo-inspector/ibkclpciafdglkjkcibmohobjkcfkaef?hl=pt-BR) e [checklists](http://www.clickminded.com/seo-checklist/) tratando sobre o assunto.