# Quando devo utilizar a meta tag keyword?

Tags: seo

Devo ter uma `<meta name="keywords" content=""/>` para cada pagina do meu site, ou posso usar a mesma para todas as paginas ?

Comment: Se não me engano, essa tag não deve mais ser usada

Comment: Achei um [artigo](http://www.conversion.com.br/blog/meta-keywords-2-bons-motivos-para-nao-usar/) interessante sobre o assunto

Comment: Bom dia Fabricio, SEO é um aspecto que demanda constante atualização. Meta Keywords, por ser muito atacada por Spammers, está em absoluto declínio. Você deve usar? Não. Minha sugestão é alterar a pergunta para: SEO: Quando devo usar a Meta Tag Keyword? e permitir uma resposta bem completa da comunidade.

Comment: Acho que já foi respondido aqui [Meta keywords ainda é necessário?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126377/70) e [Uso de meta keywords](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23598/70)

Comment: Apesar de meta tags não estar mais tão em alta ainda sim o uso dela de forma mais direta e relacionada a página continua dando resultados e ajudando os buscadores a apresentar sua página quando há uma busca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabrício,

o mais importante para o seu site está baseado na definição do Título (principalmente), Descrição da Página e URL, e estes elementos devem ser únicos para cada página e também devem incluir a palavra-chave.

Por ex, se estamos falando de '**perder pero**'. Seria uma ótima pratica sua URL conter a palavra '**perder-peso**-xxxxxx', assim como a meta description, por ex: 'Como **perder peso** em 2 semanas com a formula xxxx', da mesma forma com o título da página.

Não utilizaria meta tag na página com diversas palavras-chave relacionadas ao seu projeto, isso também pode ser identificado como 'Keyword Stuffing', além de todo seu trabalho de pesquisa e planejamento de palavras-chave estar disponível para qualquer webmaster ou especialista de SEO.

Se puder, assista esta [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=49&v=RBTBEfd7z_Y) do Matt Cutts

Espero ter ajudado.